# embed font into pdf using itextsharp

Tags: pdf, fonts, itext

I am trying to embed a font using itextsharp 5.2.1.0, but am getting errors. the font is KozGoPro-Light.otf which after doing a bit of research is a japenese font. I have tried the following...

```
        Dim tblx1 As PdfPTable = New PdfPTable(1)
        Dim tblrightcell_margin2 As PdfPCell
        Dim bfR As iTextSharp.text.pdf.BaseFont

        **bfR = iTextSharp.text.pdf.BaseFont.CreateFont("KozGoPro-Light.otf", iTextSharp.text.pdf.BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, iTextSharp.text.pdf.BaseFont.EMBEDDED)
        fntKozgoProExtra = New Font(bfR, 18)**

        tblrightcell_margin2 = New PdfPCell(New Phrase("testing....", fntKozgoProExtra))

        tblx1.AddCell(tblrightcell_margin2)
```

When i try add the font to a phrase, it will say Object reference not set to an instance of an object. If I change iTextSharp.text.pdf.BaseFont.IDENTITY_H to CP1252 or any of those encodings it will just show incorrectly on the pdf. Any clues?

Comment: using itextsharp 5.2.1.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use `IDENTITY_H` for an encoding iTextSharp automatically turns on font subsetting. Unfortunately there [appears to still be a bug](http://itext-general.2136553.n4.nabble.com/Font-subset-failure-td3574468.html) in that code. The solution for now is to just turn off subsetting for that font:

```
bfR = iTextSharp.text.pdf.BaseFont.CreateFont(FontFile, iTextSharp.text.pdf.BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, iTextSharp.text.pdf.BaseFont.EMBEDDED)
bfR.Subset = False
```

Comment: I see the bug link you show was June 2011, but I just downloaded the latest iText version and it seems this bug still exists(!). Is there a bug tracker by any chance for this so I can track the progress?

Comment: I don't know if there's a public bug database but you can ask on their mailing list (make sure to read the rules first) https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/itext-questions