# Fonts not being Embedded in ItextSharp

Tags: fonts, itext

I have a print process where we do not permit font substitution to maintain integrity of the document.  The only way to accomplish this is to ensure that all fonts are embedded.  I am specifying the embedded option when I call the FontFactory.GetFont(string fontname,string encoding,bool embedded,float size) overload.  The code below is a test code that I have been using to try to figure out a solution.  Unfortunately the pdf generated does not have the fonts embedded.

```
    public static void TestPDFEmbedd()
    {
        Document document = new Document();
        PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream(SystemPaths.SystemPath + "\\Production\\Test.pdf", FileMode.Create));
        document.Open();
        FontFactory.Register("c:\\windows\\fonts\\tahomabd.ttf","address_font");
        Font font = FontFactory.GetFont("address_font",BaseFont.CP1252,true,10f);
        document.Add(new Paragraph("Testing 123", font));
        document.Close();

    }
```

Comment: If you see Helvetica instead of Tahoma Bold, your path to the font is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

This problem can not be reproduced. A test resulted in the following PDF:

[image]

I realize that this is not an answer, but this was the only way I could think of to share a screen shot. In reality, there is no answer to the question, because the problem that is described can't be reproduced using the information that was shared.

As you can see, iTextSharp has embedded the font. More specifically, a subset of the font. If you want to embed the full font, you need to use the approach explained in the answer to this question: [embed font into pdf using itextsharp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10486459/embed-font-into-pdf-using-itextsharp)

Reading that answer, you will also notice that there were some bugs with fonts in the past; when people complain about something that doesn't work, we always assume that they are using a recent version. This assumption is reasonable, because it doesn't make sense for people to complain about a bug that was fixed many years ago.

Comment: I had version 5.5.7, installed version 5.5.9 and came up with the same issue.  I changed the font from tahomabd.ttf to tahoma.ttf and it resulted in a pdf with the font embedded.  I swithced back to tahomabd.ttf and it would not embed.  tried cour.ttf among others and it would not embed either.  The font names shown are similar but different.  For example on the tahomabd.ttf it shows as tahoma-bold and it's substituted for tahoma,bold.  Could it be something wrong with windows 10?

Comment: I was able to replicate your scenario, the documents property and the preflight function show the font embedded.  When I go to "Tools->Advanced Editing->Touch up Text Tool"  and highlight the text and view the properties, it says that the font is not available for viewing. There seems to be a discrepancy in Acrobat Reader Pro

Comment: Did you read my answer? I explained that *a subset of the font* is embedded. This is reflected in the document properties and the PDF passes preflight when you check if the font is embedded. However, you want to use the font to add text. That won't work. For instance: the text "Testing 123" doesn't contain the letter **a**. Hence you can't add any Tahoma Bold text with that letter, because it's not in the embedded subset.

Comment: Thanks, I did read your answer and understood perfectly.  I do understand the subsetting.  We do not plan on editing the document once created.  I had used the text touch up tool kit to verify that it was being embedded, which I guess was the wrong tool to verify.  I have updated our system and are in the process of printing a test to verify but we do not see any problems right now.  Thanks again for your help